# Declare variable of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class ViewModel<TPrimaryModel> : ObservableObject
    where TPrimaryModel : TwoNames, new()
{
    ...
}
```

In another class I would like to declare a variable where a ViewModel could be saved to:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private ViewModel _currentViewModel;
}
```

This doesn't work as 2 parameters are required (because of the generic).
I don't mind which ViewModel is saved to _currentViewModel, as long as the object inherits from the abstract class ViewModel.

This doesn't work as well:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    #region Members
    private ViewModel<TwoNames> _currentViewModel;
    #endregion
}
```

Compiler error:

```
The type 'typename' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'parameter' in the generic type or method 'generic'
```

This is because TwoNames is an abstract class. Removing the "new()" constraint isn't a solution for me as I need to instantiate new objects of "TwoNames" in my abstract class (ViewModel). Any other idea?

Comment: Can't you create non-generc base for for your `ViewModel`? Btw: constraint `TViewModel : ViewModel<TViewModel, TPrimaryModel>` looks quite strange..

Comment: Either `MainViewModel` also needs to be generic or you need to introduce a non-generic class in your hierarchy which inherits from `ObservableObject` and in turn is inherited from by `ViewModel<T1,T2>`.

Comment: You're right. This constraint was redundant and not needed. Fixed it & updated my question.

MainViewModel shouldn't be generic as there will only be exactly 1 MainViewModel object. Is there any way without introducing a non-generic class of ViewModel?

Comment: What's the benefit of making your base viewmodel generic?

Comment: I need to make us of those generics, like PrimaryModel = new TPrimaryModel(); ... This saves me a lot of code in the classes which inherit from my ViewModel generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a non-generic base class:

```
public abstract class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...
}

public abstract class ViewModel<TPrimaryModel> : ViewModel
    where TPrimaryModel : TwoNames, new()
{
    ...
}
```

And declare `_currentViewModel` as type `ViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    #region Members
    private ViewModel _currentViewModel;
    #endregion
}
```